# How do I come to a series expansion of $1/(e^z-1)^2?$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How do I come to a series expansion of $\frac{1}{(e^z-1)^2}?$

$e^z-1$ can be expanded to: 
$$1 + z + \frac{1}{2} z^2 + \frac{1}{6} z^3 + \dots -1$$

so the series becomes:
$$\frac{1}{(z^2 (1 + \frac{1}{2} z + \frac{1}{6} z^2 +\dots)^2}$$

I don't now how to make the step to:
$$\frac{1}{z^2}(1 - z + \frac{5}{12} z^2 + \dots)$$

Comment: I've got it. Use the binomial expansion:
$(1+x)^n=1+nx+n(n-1)/2! x + ...$
With n=-2.

Thanks for the effort tho!

Answer (score -1):

Use long division or alternatively restart by considering instead $1/(1-z)^2=1+2z+3z^2+4z^3+\dots$ and substituting in from there.

Comment: Okay, well now, how do I come from $1/(1-z)^2$ to $1+2z+3z^2+4z^3..$?... That would solve the whole problem for me. It is the method that is troubling me.

Comment: Well surely you're familiar with $1/(1-z)=1+z+z^2+z^3+\dots$. Differentiate both sides, doing the series term by term.